# Font size is bigger than set

Tags: android, fonts, size

i have a problem with text in android.

Let's say i make TextView with font size 100px, now I'm entering text: TÓjy
Meassuring this text on screen of device, gives me around 115px height from highest point of font to lowest.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:textSize="100px"
    android:text="TYyÓj" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I want to be sure that if i set 100px font size, it will be 100px height, is there a way to achieve this?

First one is with 100px height, second is on wrap_content, on first one y is cut.
[image: First one is with 100px height, second is on wrap_content]

Comment: You want to set font-size of the `TextView` ? or according to your question, you are entering text ?

Comment: please put your code here for better understanding.

Comment: pass 100sp rather 100px .

Comment: code please.We can't help you without knowing the code you use.

Comment: @BirajZalavadia I Know that proper approach is entering in sp, rather in px, but i need to know exact size of view, and in this particular case i don't need support for scaled pixels.

Comment: Please give your textview size in "dp" (density independent pixels).

Comment: @Ritaban i have own logic that calculates view size, it's just simplified example.   Main question is, why 100px is not fitting 100px height view. Why text is bigger than it was set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with another 2 or 3 fonts: give them each an extra 15% vertical space and see if they all universally fit.

If they don't, then the answer to your question is no (as I suspect).  A font has no contract that for a given point size it must actually fit in it; it's merely a suggestion that the font designer has the liberty to play with.  Read the second paragraph here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)

I don't see why the same idea wouldn't apply to pixels in digital typography as well, especially since pixels have no standard use as measuring devices in digital typesetting.

Comment: Both answers were useful, but i decided to mark this one, wiki article helped a lot, nice to know such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to be sure that if i set 100px font size, it will be 100px
>   height, is there a way to achieve this?

Unfortunately, no.

Setting the textSize to`100px` does not guarantee that the text will take up 100px in height. This is because of the relative placement between the characters that a font style supports. A capital `Y` has a different (x, y) placement than a lowercase `y`. This is clear from your own example.

Setting `layout_height="wrap_content"` *is* the best option.